# Can phasers be replicated?

Tags: star-trek, replicator, phaser

Assuming that I have access to a replicator without any security restrictions, could I replicate a phaser with the replicator? Would it be replicated charged, or would I have to charge it?

Comment: I am only now just remembering the DS9 episode where the Cardassian replicators created self-targeting phasers ready to fire. I assume they were drawing energy from the replicator as opposed to being precharged though. Not sure about a Federation replicator though.

Comment: I don't see why my comment needed to be edited to remove any trace of humour or levity.

Comment: amusing as it was IMHO it made the question slightly unclear

Comment: You can’t just [replicate a weapon](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-22421185)!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Yes, absolutely you can.

In the episode [TNG: Samaritan Snare](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Samaritan_Snare_(episode)), the Pakled take Geordi's phaser from him and ***replicate several more***.

Quoting from the screenplay

> **REGINOD:** (re: the phaser) *We can make more.*
>
> Geordi reacts, realizing:
>
> **GEORDI:** *You have a replicator?*
>
> **GREBNEDLOG:** (with pride) *It is not broken.*
>
> **GEORDI:** *I didn't come here to give you weapons.*
>
> **GREBNEDLOG:** (re: the phaser, points it at Geordi) *You will make more*.

then shortly afterwards...

> **The viewscreen comes alive with the image of Grebnedlog holding
> Geordi's phaser in his mitt. Reginod and the other Pakleds all hold
> replicated versions of the original now.** Geordi is in the background,
> slowly struggling to his feet once again, propped up by Reginod as
> other Pakleds play recklessly with their phasers. One of them takes a
> shot at his comrade, missing him, like children playing with dangerous
> toys. Grebnedlog turns to face the viewscreen
>
> <sub><sup>[TNG: Samaritan Snare - Script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/143.txt)</sup></sub>

Since the Pakled lack a basic understanding of how the phasers work, it seems vanishingly unlikely that they could work out how to charge them. They must have come out of the replicator fully charged.

Comment: I recall phasers being replicated in TOS.

Comment: I wonder if such phasers would be as reliable as the originals, or if it's like 3D printed firearms of today where they work but are quickly warped out of nominal tolerances by the forces involved.

Answer (score 3):

## Most probably yes

The [Memory Alpha page on replicators](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Replicator) explains that replicator technology uses:

> transporter technology to dematerialize quantities of matter and then rematerialize that matter in another form

Hence, I don't see any reason why a fully-operational phaser couldn't be replicated.  I doubt that it would be replicated charged though; I expect it would need to be charged manually.

Also consider the following quote:

> On Starfleet installations and starships, if a person in custody is confined to quarters, it is standard policy to disable the replicators that the person has access to, in order **to ensure that a weapon cannot be replicated.** (DS9: "Inquisition"; VOY: "Counterpoint")

Bear in mind that it is probably *physically* capable of producing a phaser; one would need to program one into the replicator itself.

Comment: A knife or current era gun would be weapons. I don't think that quote supports the idea that a phaser could be made.

Comment: @HighInBC considering they use force-fields, a weapon like a knife or gun wouldn't be of much use to a prisoner; they'd need something like a phaser to drain or disable the force-field

Comment: How many episodes have you seen where a prisoner attacks the guard when the door opens? The policy would be to prohibit any type of weapon or for that matter tools that could be used to tamper.

Comment: @HighInBC I've changed the answer in light of those points slightly ;)

Comment: +1 for a good answer. Backed up by the fact that in DS9's Civil Defense the replicators did create energy weapons. It is still not clear if they had an internal energy supply or if they were feeding power from the replicators.

Answer (score -1):

If the replication pattern for a weapon exists it can presumably be replicated. However the energy needed to charge it consumes vastly more energy than a evening dinner.
In the Voyager episode "Counterpoint" Janeway alots quarters to a new arrival but shutsdown the replicator in his quarters as a safety precaution.
*JANEWAY: I'm afraid that won't be possible. I had your replicator taken offline.
KASHYK: In case I decided to replicate a weapon.
JANEWAY: A safety precaution. You understand.
KASHYK: Better than anyone. *

In the TNG episode "The Mind's Eye" The Federation is accused by Klingon delegation of providing weapons to Klingon colony independence seekers. Upon analysis the rifle being examined shows instances of being charged with an alternative power supply.

- *VAGH: Romulan replications using stolen Federation technology*

If the Romulans can replicate a Federation style weapon so could the federation. But like the TR-116 it's replication pattern is secured presumably that only starfleet officers could utilize and make one.

Comment: Your example seems a poor choice. Janeway could have been referring to anything as a weapon including knives and sharp edges